# Using if else statements correctly

Tags: java, junit, selenium

I have the following code, but I'm looking for a way to make the code read easier.

```
public void synchronizePageAndExcecuteVerifyNode() throws Exception {
    String nameTestcase = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    WriteTo.testgoal(nameTestcase, TestgoalState.nvt, "");

    Boolean testDataGenerated = eventTestData.eventDetailMultipleDays;
    Boolean currentPage = driver.getTitle().contains(Value.TITLE_EVENT_MULTIPLE_DAYS);

    if (testDataGenerated == true) {
        if(currentPage == true){
            this.verifyEventDetailFull();
        }else{
            WriteTo.testgoal(nameTestcase, TestgoalState.NOK,
                    "Page synchronize failed");
            throw new Exception("PAGE SYNCHRONIZE FAILED");
        }
    } else {
        WriteTo.testgoal(nameTestcase, TestgoalState.NOK,
                "testdata is not generated");
        throw new Exception("NO TESTDATA GENERATED");
    }
}
```

Comment: To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Comment: there is one function that creates a testdata node on a website by using the selenium library. After the creation of the testdata, i want to verify the page that was just created. Only before the the verify i want to check that the testdata is created and that I am on the correct page.

Comment: @Apjuh The comment should be included in the question. Comments are not the right place to make that kind of precision on a question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**`if (condition == true)`**

Instead of

```
if (testDataGenerated == true) {
```

just write

```
if (testDataGenerated) {
```

**Rewriting `if`s**

You can move your checks to the top of the method like this to avoid nested ifs:

```
    if (!testDataGenerated) {
        WriteTo.testgoal(nameTestcase, TestgoalState.NOK,
                "testdata is not generated");
        throw new Exception("NO TESTDATA GENERATED");
    }
    if(!currentPage){
        WriteTo.testgoal(nameTestcase, TestgoalState.NOK,
                "Page synchronize failed");
        throw new Exception("PAGE SYNCHRONIZE FAILED");
    }
    this.verifyEventDetailFull();
```

Comment: Instinctively how I would have written that, as soon as I saw the poster code above my first thought was to handle the exceptions at the top.

Answer (score 12):

- Are you sure that you need a `Boolean`? Considering how your code looks, `currentPage` and `testDataGenerated` cannot be null (if they would be then they would throw a `NullPointerException`. Use `boolean` instead which cannot be set to `null`
- Try to avoid throwing `Exception`, create or use a subclass of `Exception` instead.
- Speaking of "make the code read easier", there is no need to use CAPS LOCK FOR THE EXCEPTION MESSAGES. (Sorry, just had to show you what I mean).
- Use spacing more consistently:

  ```
  if (testDataGenerated) {
  ```

  is better than

  ```
  if(currentPage){
  ```

  Just like `} else {` is better than `}else{`

Comment: -1, formatting isn't better with spaces, nor without. I agree with consistency, but spacing or no spacing is entirely opinion based.

Comment: Well, you can't just -1 for ONE part of an answer that seems opinion based, when the rest is good.

Comment: @Kilazur sure he can. Although I would disagree. The [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#475) as well as the [google](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.6.2-horizontal-whitespace) style guide have a definite opinion on this. And even though there are no studies as to what is more readable, most Java programmers are used to the first version. (of course, any IDE can change this easily. But it can also change inconsistent spacing, which most people would agree is not acceptable.)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have provide some good suggestions about the code formatting and styling, so here's mine on the logic.

The way I see it, you only need to call `verifyEventDetailFull()` when the test data is generated and `currentPage` is `true` (I'm not quite sure why the title containing a certain value is 'current page', but that's beyond my point). Otherwise, you 'handle the error' by saying that 'Page synchronize failed' if the test data is generated but `currentPage` is `false`, or say 'Test data is not generated' if that is indeed the case.

Given some slight, and in my humble opinion reasonable, assumptions based on the cases I have described above, I have an implementation for the handle error part:

```
private void handleError(final String testCaseName, final String errorDescription) {
    WriteTo.testgoal(testCaseName, TestgoalState.NOK, errorDescription);
    throw new Exception(errorDescription);
}
```

I think it's fair enough to use one `errorDescription` for printing some output and using it for the `Exception` message. I will now present the full suggestion:

```
public void synchronizePageAndExcecuteVerifyNode() throws Exception {
    final String testCaseName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    WriteTo.testgoal(testCaseName, TestgoalState.nvt, "");
    boolean isTestDataGenerated = eventTestData.eventDetailMultipleDays;
    if (isTestDataGenerated && driver.getTitle().contains(Value.TITLE_EVENT_MULTIPLE_DAYS)) {
        verifyEventDetailFull();
    } else {
        handleError(testCaseName, isTestDataGenerated ? "Page synchronize failed" : "Test data is not generated");
    }
}

private void handleError(final String testCaseName, final String errorDescription) {
    WriteTo.testgoal(testCaseName, TestgoalState.NOK, errorDescription);
    throw new Exception(errorDescription);
}
```

The only `boolean` value I need to store first is `isTestDataGenerated`. It is a good naming convention to begin `boolean` variables with `is`. Inside the `else` part, `isTestDataGenerated` allows us to switch between the correct error description. As mentioned above, we will only encounter the 'Page synchronize failed' case when the `if` condition holds `true` for `isTestDataGenerated` but `false` for 'current page'. Or you can simply read it as there is no test data generated, hence that error description in the `false` clause of the conditional operator.

Answer (score 4):

Names of variables should be chosen well. If you name a variable `currentPage`, I would assume that it contains a page number (1, 2, 3, 4, etc). If you want a boolean variable that is true if we are on the current page, you could call it `isCurrentPage`. If you want a boolean variable that is true if synchronization to the current page succeeded (I have no idea what that means in the context, but that's what you seem to be checking), call it `isSynchronizedToCurrentPage`.

Especially when you change `currentPage == true` to `currentPage`, the first one indicates that `currentPage` is some kind of boolean. Reading `if (currentPage)` I only think "What???".